# Jquery AJAX from remote host

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi I am trying to get json from a remote host using this piece of code [Example at fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KNfVz/1/),

Here i want to add that i am using jquery cross domain ajax plugin

```
$("button").click(function() {
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://50.116.19.49/rest/user.json",
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result) {
    $("div").html(result.responseText);
    }
  });
});​
```

I am using jquery AJAX GET method. The problem is when i try to use POST instead of GET it stops working, Need help.!

Thanks

Comment: user.json is a file? a public method?

Comment: Possible dublicate with [Jquery Get json from remote host][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990520/jquery-get-json-from-remote-host

Comment: Cross-domain restriction

Comment: But it is working with GET so why not POST

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to limit request by method on server side.

So that doesn't mean If it works with `GET` than that also must work with `POST`. As I see your web service doesn't allow origin access for `POST` method.

Here is an example how it's allowed for different type of request in `PHP`

```
<?php
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
     echo "lan";
  else {
     echo "disabled";
  } 
?>
```